# scala.MatchError when partitioning a string with an optional part into one or three parts

Tags: regex, scala, regex-group

I am trying to pull out something like this:

```
params = {"path", "contentName"}
```

part of `parametersStr` below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/breezeQuery", params = {"path", "contentName"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Why is this code giving me a `scala.MatchError`?:

```
val paramsPattern = """(.*)(?:params = \{.*})?(.*)""".r
val paramsPattern(left, paramsStr, right) = parametersStr
```

Also, the pattern like this may not occur in the string.  So I also want to know if that is the case.  Finally, I'm capturing everything to the left and right of the group so that I can concatenate them to remove the captured group from the string.  It is optional, but I do want to capture it if it is present.

Comment: Do you mean you need a string output, like `"""params = {"path", "contentName"}"""`? But why did you wrap that part with a non-capturing group then? Why is it optional?

Comment: Yes, I need a string output like that.  I probably should not have wrapped that part with a non-capturing group.  How I should not is part of the question.  It is optional because it may not be there for other strings.

Comment: So, if you have `@RequestMapping(value = "/breezeQuery", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, should it all land in `left`?

Comment: If it all lands in left, that's fine.  That's a separate, later problem.

Comment: Then see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to partition the string into 3 or 2 parts (depending on the optional `params = \{.*}`).

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:(params\s*=\s*\{.*?})(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wbnM2j/1). **Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (*left*):
- `(?:(params\s*=\s*\{.*?})(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group, will be tried at least once:

  - `(params\s*=\s*\{.*?})`  - Group 2 (*paramsStr*):`params` word, `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, `{`, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as fewas possible and then `}`
  - `(.*)`  - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/e7H5hS):

```
val parametersStr = """@RequestMapping(value = "/breezeQuery", params = {"path", "contentName"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)"""
val paramsPattern = """^(.*?)(?:(params\s*=\s*\{.*?})(.*))?$""".r
val paramsPattern(left, paramsStr, right) = parametersStr
println(s"Left: $left\nParam String: $paramsStr\nRight: $right")
```

Output:

```
Left: @RequestMapping(value = "/breezeQuery", 
Param String: params = {"path", "contentName"}
Right: , method = RequestMethod.GET)
```